# Validation form on dependant radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a project in witch I need to have a custom validation on a form from dependant radio button or checkboxes.

Here is my HTML code,

```
<form name="form" nonvalidate ng-controller="Part6CtrlForm">
.
.
.
<md-input-container class="choice">
                <input name ="is-correct"type="radio" ng-value="true" ng-model="choise.is_correct"/>
              </md-input-container>
                <!-- <md-checkbox share-validate ng-model="choice.is_correct" aria-label="Is Correct ?">
                    Is correct ?
                </md-checkbox> -->

</form>
```

I have the two possibility, I need to have only one checkbox or radio to be checked and set a true value when it's checked. 
My problem is that I can't find a way to do the form validation on that rule.

I have tried some code in js but I'm new with angular and so even after a lot a search I haven't find anything that help me.

```
$scope.validResponses = function () {

        this.sum = 0;
        this.valid = false;
        this.tmpBool = 0;

        for (i ; i<choices.length ; i++)
        {
            this.tmpBool = $scope.choices[i].is_correct ? 1 :0;
            this.sum += this.tmpBool;
        }
        console.log(sum);

        return sum===1 ? true : false;

   };
```

This function try to count how many checkboxes are checked but I'm not familiar with $scope and so it's not working.

Thank you for help.

Comment: The radio buttons are supposed to be single selection mechanism. You won't need to validate it if you will do this in a way like this
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio